# Custom TextField

Tags: swift, label, core-graphics

I am trying to build a scientific calculator app. However, the simple label does not fit my needs, as it can't display symbols like e.g. integral or fractions. So I want to develop my own custom label class.

I've already tried to draw numbers and symbols using Core Graphics, but I can't really figure out how to draw a Cursor that is blinking. Do you have any suggestions for my problem, or should I use something different than CG? Best regards!

```
func drawText(text: String) {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 343, height: 306))
        let image = renderer.image { ctx in
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
            let attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 36)!, NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
            text.draw(with: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 343, height: 306), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attrs, context: nil)
        }
        imageView.image = image
    }

func drawCursor() {
        // Don't know how to continue here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use unicode symbols for representing something like integrals, Below is the code that draws integral symbol.

```
let textField = UITextField()
textField.text = "\u{222B}"
```

You can also find unicodes for all the other characters just by simple google search.

Regarding drawing cursor you can use Timer for blinking effect. Below is the code that might help you to get some logic,

```
let textField = UITextField()
let text = "SomeText"
var count = 0
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { (_) in
    var displayText = ""
    if count % 2 == 0 {
        displayText = "\(text)|"
    } else {
        displayText = text
    }

    textField.text = displayText
    print(textField.text ?? "")

    count += 1
}
```

If you want to display cursor in the middle of the text, you need to track it's position and insert it in the middle.

Edit:- Rather than searching for unicode on the Internet,(as @rmaddy suggested) you can just goto Edit menu -> Emojis & Symbols and get the symbol you want.

Comment: Instead of `"\u{222B}"` which is hard to read, use the character directly. `"∫"`.

Comment: I don't think we have this symbol on mac keyboard. But as you said we can copy it from the internet.

Comment: No need copy it from the Internet. In any macOS program, click the Edit menu and select  Emoji & Symbols. Now you can find and use any Unicode character in your code.

Comment: Ohh. Great, thanks. I am gonna add this to the answer.